# vector calculus book for Green's theorem

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis, book-recommendation, greens-theorem

I am finding good vector calculus books for rigorous proof of Green's theorem since I have learnt cauchy's theorem in complex analysis can be proved so easily. Can anyone recommend??

+: is calculus on manifold by spivak also good to learn Greene's theorem???

Comment: I like Mathematical Analysis by Apostol. I don't personally care for Spivak's book.

Comment: Personally, I would say to go with Spivak's book. For you, it depends on your background. I am quite an 'algebraic viewpoint' lover and I don't have a hard time understanding abstract algebraic definition. On the other side, geometric definitions give me a hard time. If you start the section about Integration On Chains and you like it, then consider continuing.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins The second edition of Apostol's book doesn't discuss line integrals.

Comment: Spivak's book has Green's theorem as a special case of the generalized Stokes theorem. However, it's a bit difficult to read. Other possibilities would be *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich or *Advanced Calculus* by Loomis and Sternberg, which prove the general Stokes theorem on manifolds. I imagine there must be a book that addresses the special case of Green's theorem rigorously with less machinery, so perhaps you could specify if that's what you's prefer.

Comment: @user49640 That's a shame. I haven't read the second edition. I was referring to Chapter 10 in the first edition.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins It seems the first edition's treatment of vector analysis relies heavily on Jordan's curve theorem and related results which aren't proved. Instead, Apostol refers the reader to other sources for these proofs.